# Set-ExecutionPolicy which is the right one?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script which is stored in a shared Folder on a machine in my Domain. Now I want to run this script on a Server which is in DMZ. What ExecutionPolicy must de domain server and the dmz server have to run this script? "Everyone" has "full rights" to run the script, but It doesn't work.

can I do that with `set-executionpolicy`?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For running remote scripts you either need `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, run the script with `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, or [sign the scripts](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx).

Note that bypassing or changing the execution policy will only work if it's not enforced with a local or group policy.